# R: splom()--> how to delete the default x-lab title?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

whenever I do a scatterplot with three variables with the function "splom" in R, the graphic in the plot-window shows the plot but with a title "Scatter Plot Matrix" at the bottom.

How can I delete this title, due to that I only want a title on the top??

Here I insert the code:

```
splom(~example, 
      panel = function(x,y) {
        panel.xyplot(x,y)
        lm <- lm(y~x)
        panel.ablineq(reg=lm, r.squared = TRUE, rotate=TRUE, col.line="red")
```

Thank you in advance and best regards!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `xlab = NULL` to your `splom`.